# Show recently executed stored procedures, including parameters

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

This sql kindly provided by Microsoft lets me see the recently executed stored procedures, but not the values that were passed as parameters.

Where should I look for that information?

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    d.object_id, d.database_id, 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) 'proc name', 
    d.cached_time, d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time, 
    d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],
    d.last_elapsed_time, d.execution_count
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d
ORDER BY 
    [total_worker_time] DESC;
```

Comment: I don't think that sort of information is persisted in any place (by default). All you got was a query to a procedure statistical usage system table. It's used for optmization

Comment: Perhaps too late to get the information for the past but for the future, you could just create an audit / log table and insert desired values ( maybe including user-information ) from the SPROC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That information doesn't really exist anywhere (unless, as others have suggested, you store it yourself). However, you can see it by using SQL Profiler or Extended Events. With SQL Profiler, you need to choose the `RPC:Completed` and `SQL:BatchCompleted` events, and make sure that the `TextData` column is selected for both.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have you stored procedure insert into someTable on the database.

Something like

```
INSERT INTO someTable (Value) 
SELECT @StoredProcedureInsertParamter
```